# How to read large tif file in Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I have a tif file larger than 100MB. It seems that PIL.Image cannot work properly on the tif file.

```
In [1]: x = Image.open('top_myfile_RGB.tif')

In [2]: x

Out[2]: <PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=RGB size=6000x6000 at 0x7F4E55CDB940>

In [3]: x.save('~/Desktop/test.tif')
```

> ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image

I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the size of the tif file.

Thanks is advance!

[image source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1huhPvAJ0dHzDqpEzyVZFiqjBucG_jkKJ/view?usp=sharing%22image%20source%22)

Comment: Could you upload the image to make it accessible online? The problem might be specific to it.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Please access the image through the google drive link above.

Comment: So that's a tiled GeoTIFF with 608x608 blocks. The fact that image width and height is not divisible by block width and height might be causing the error.

Comment: PIL version 1.1.7 fails on my system with a different error `_TIFFVSetField: tst.tiff: Invalid tag "TileOffsets" (not supported by codec)`. Consider using `gdal` instead of `PIL` for this image. Also there is a similar [post on GIS.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/267989/7086) regarding PIL support for advanced TIFF features that remains unanswered for more than a month.

Comment: I switched to `gdal`. It's working fine now!

Comment: [Tifffile.py](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html) also works with this image.